# Presto SQL WHERE filter for a column that contains an array of structs

Tags: sql, presto

In the following table, I want to filter for all rows that contain the name, Alice.

```
WITH data AS (
   SELECT  ARRAY[CAST(ROW('Bob') AS ROW(name VARCHAR))] AS users
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT  ARRAY[CAST(ROW('Alice') AS ROW(name VARCHAR))] AS users
)
SELECT * 
FROM data

+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| users                                                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| [{name=Bob}]                                                    |
| [{name=Alice}]                                                  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If users were a string I could say:

`SELECT * from data where users like '%Alice%'`

but users is an array of struct. `array<struct<name:string>>`

I'm executing the query on [Amazon AWS Athena which uses Presto 0.172](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/presto-functions.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use one of the array-processing functions to select the relevant rows. [`any_match`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/array.html?highlight=any_match#any_match) returns true if any of the elements in the array matches the given condition:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM data
WHERE any_match(users, user -> user.name = 'Alice')
```

Note that the answer involving `CROSS JOIN` and `UNNEST` only works if each array contains a single user.

Comment: The Presto version I'm using doesn't have `any_match`.

However, I found this: https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/1036

And, I changed this to: `WHERE contains(transform(users, user -> user.name = 'Alice'), true);`

That worked. :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
select t.*
from t cross join
     unnest(t.users) u(user)
where user.name = 'Alice';
```

I'm not sure what the "struct" looks like.  Perhaps you just want:

```
where user like '%Alice%'
```

Comment: This is more expensive than just checking in the array contains the name